# Authentication issue with %run, long-running code, and saving data in Azure databricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using the %run feature in Azure databricks to execute many notebooks in sequence from a command notebook. One notebook has a single line of code which is a long computation on a dataset (~ 5 hrs) and I want to save the output of this. I tried including the save step at the end of the long-running notebook, but the save times out (see error below). I'm only seeing this error when the long-running notebook takes 2+ hrs to run. Is there any way I can automate this?

I'm able to pass the data I want back through the %run feature in the command notebook and save the data there, but I have to run the save manually after the long-running notebook, otherwise I get the same authentication timeout error. I'd like to be able to have one notebook where I only need to click "run all".

[image]

Comment: are you running on the high concurrency cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I find it is better to break up long notebooks into smaller ones and use the multi-task job scheduler to help run them in order.

If a single line of code cannot be broken up (per comment), then I wonder if the single line is being parallelized. If so, maybe you need more workers. If not, then using a large single node cluster would be my suggestion if parallelizing is not an option.

Comment: I should clarify that the long-running part is a single line of code that I can't spread across multiple jobs.